# only backgroundColor style in if function javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dom

```
for (e = 0; e < occs.length; e++) {
  if (occs[e][0] == year && occs[e][1] == mon && occs[e][2] == dt) {
    cls.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(100,240,100, 1)";
    cls.innerHTML += "<b>*</b>";
  } else {
    cls.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255, 1)";
  };
};
```

everything is running well but when i use code to remove style in else section it is not working

Comment: Dude , explain  to us what do you want to do with this code .

Comment: Is it allready in DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You need check cls is undefined or not by update code as below.

I have sample your code set background work well.

```
for(e=0;e<occs.length;e++){
        if(occs[e][0] == year && occs[e][1]==mon && occs[e][2]==dt){
        if(cls == null || cls == undefined){
           alert("not found cls");
        }
        cls.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(100,240,100, 1)" ;
        cls.innerHTML += "<b>*</b>" ;
    }else{
        cls.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255, 1)" ;
    }; 
};
```

```js
let cls = document.getElementById("test");
cls.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(100,240,100, 1)" ;
```

```html
<div id="test">Test background</div>
```